# (libgit2) Determine whether a push/fetch refspec requires force

Tags: git, libgit2

The man pages for `git-fetch(1)` and `git-push(1)` specify complex semantics for when a push/fetch refspec is allowed without push. For example, `refs/heads` only accepts commits but allows fast forward, while `refs/tags` accepts any object but rejects any updates. Does libgit2 implement any functionality to evaluate this?

I would prefer to avoid writing my own logic to evaluate this based on the git man page, especially since it won't be future proof, and constructing a shadow repository then shelling out to git to see what it does, while hilarious, is slow and brittle.

Note that I'm asking specifically about the rules for updating refs, not how to perform merge analysis/determine whether a fast forward is possible between two commits.